# mini apps android samsung

Tags: android, android-intent

playing around with a new samsung tablet i noticed they have mini apps on the menu bar that you can overlay like a windows machine over any app you are currently in.  Is this strictly samsung touch wiz or something that can natively be created / developed?

Comment: Is strictly a Samsung UI think AFAIK. Could theoretically be done on any device, but would require modifications to the system.

Comment: Any documentation on how to write one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mini apps bar / tray icon are features designed by Samsung. They developed them.
The feature is not related with the Touch Wiz Laucher itself (for instance, you can develop your own Launcher, and the mini apps tray will continue to appear.

About write or modify these feature: This is a more complicated issue, because Samsung doesn't publish their version of the Android, so we can't see what is implemented.

I think that the only thing you can do is blocking or uninstall the mini apps that appear in the bottom list.

Hope this helped you.